# How to get the name of an Object

Tags: c++, class, object

I am coding a little RPG(Role Playing Game)

Here is the situation: I created an object *Personnage*.
In my classes, I created a method *atttaquer*. But I would like that after calling my method *attaquer* it writes something like this: *Goliath attaque David* . But to that, I need to grab the name of the Object. Because the player may want to edit the name of Object (The personage name) before playing.

There is my code:
Personnage.h

```
#ifndef Personnage_h
#define Personnage_h
#include <string>
#include "Arme.h"
class Personnage{

//methods
public:
Personnage();
Personnage(std::string nomArme, int degatsArme);
Personnage(int vie, int mana);
// ~Personnage();
void recevoirDegats(int nbDegats);
void attaquer(Personnage &cible);

private:
// Attributs
int m_vie;
int m_magie;
std::string m_nom;
};

#endif
```

My Personnage.cpp code:

```
    #include "Personnage.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    void Personnage::recevoirDegats(int nbDegats){
        
        m_vie -= nbDegats;
        if (m_vie < 0) {
            m_vie = 0;
        }
        
    }
    
    void Personnage::attaquer(Personnage &cible){
        cible.recevoirDegats(m_arme.getDegats());
// if David attacks Goliath I want to write std::cout << David << "attaque "<< Goliath << endl; but I do not know how to grab the name of the object after it's creation

       
    }
```

There is my main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Personnage.h"
//#include "Personnage.cpp"
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;




int main()
{
    Personnage David, Goliath, Atangana("Ak47", 35);
Goliath.attaquer(David);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable names don't exist at runtime, you have to pass the name along as constructor parameter and store it in some member of `Personnage`. And write some getter function to get it.

Comment: Objects don't have names, variables do. Based on the name of the member, one would expect `m_nom` to be the object's name.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give your objects names, it cannot be the variable names. They are only meant for the compiler and they are fixed. So you need to create a class that can have a name:

```
class NamedObject
{
    private:
        std::string m_name;
    public:
       const std::string& getName() const 
       {
           return m_name;
       }
       void setName(const std::string& name)
       {
           m_name = name;
       }
}
```

And if you want your classes to have a name, the easiest way would be to derive from it:

```
class Personnage : NamedObject {
```

Then you can say:

```
Personnage player1, player2;

player1.setName("David");
player2.setName("Goliath");
```

Alternatively, you can get those string from user input.

And if you need to address one by name:

```
std::cout << player1.getName() << " please make your move." << std::endl;
```